# How can I prevent CMYK image colours being shifted when importing into Assets?

Tags: assets

When importing CMYK images into Assets the colour of the image can be shifted dramatically. Often giving a washed out look.

How can I prevent this and ensure the image colours are as accurate as possible?

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to add the following lines to your config

```
'preserveImageColorProfiles' => true,
'preserveCmykColorspace' => true
```

This will ensure that the image colours are retained when imported to Assets. You should also ensure that the images are converted to RGB for output. I do this with the Imager plugin and specify the image should be converted to RGB in my transform options.

Also, ensure that you are using ImageMagick for any transformations by installing it on your server and adding the following to your config.

```
'imageDriver' => 'imagick',
```

Comment: To add to this, the two settings will have _no_ effect if you're not using Imagick.